# SwiftUI - Context menu glitch

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a an hstack with multiple elements created in a ForEach look. Each element is a vstack with 3 text views inside and a context menu on the vstack:

```
VStack {
  Text(“”)
  Text(“”)
  Text(“”)
}
.contextMenu {
  // code
}
```

Each textview is filled with data from Published members of an ObservedObject.

When I access the menu there is a glitch in the data shown. The first picture is the initial view and the second is the glitch:
[image]

[image]

The context menu shows the data that was there when the view first appeared. When the context menu is released, then data will show the old data for a second and then switch to the new data (if it was changed by clicking one of the buttons).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Would you provide minimal reproducible example?